# Why is pesach 7 days long

Tags: number, passover

We are commanded to keep Pesach for 7 days in the Torah. I'm wondering if any reasons have been developed by anyone throughout Jewish history for why 7 days.

**In other words, what is the significance of 7 in the context of how long Pesach (and what the holiday stands for) should be celebrated?**

Additionally, for the future, how would I answer a specific/obscure question like this on my own. Would I need to brute force it by doing a whole "review of literature"? Which seforim are likely to have these kinds ideas in them?

Comment: How many days do you think it should have been that you ask about 7?

Comment: I think the Torah says that Pesach is only 1 day. Followed by a week of Chag haMatzot

Comment: @Aaron While I agree that's how the Torah used the terms, that seems to be largely a semantic game and you should be careful not to confuse this discussion with it.

Comment: @Aaron regardless of what the nuance of the wording is, that doesn't answer the question of the presumed reason by the chachomim for pesach being 7 days . In other words, I'm wondering what the significance of 7 is in the context of Pesach?